# How do i change the site logo in a flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, power-automate, flow, site-logo

I have a flow which creates a site and associates a hub. I would now like to add the logo to the site. I've found the `_api/web/SiteLogoUrl` endpoint, but can't get it to work.

Here is my step:

[image]

I have tried it without the `/SiteLogoUrl` as described in another site, but that gave an error. This method runs successfully (so it says) but doesn't update the icon.

I have also tried hardcoding the Site Address and with/without the content-type and X-HTTP-Method headers, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTTP request action like this:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Reference**:

Check this detailed article for more information: [Update SharePoint Site Logo using Power Automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/15/update-sharepoint-site-logo-using-power-automate/)

Comment: I just tried this for 2 SharePoint sites and it is working fine for me.

Comment: I missed changing none to verbose in "application/json;odata=verbose" and that's what fixed it. Working now. Thanks Ganesh.